# Can I keep the same ID in libp2p across restarts?

Tags: go, p2p, libp2p, go-libp2p

I am writing a test app. For this, it would be ideal if my libp2p nodes would keep their IDs across restarts - otherwise I need to think of some intermediate service which keeps track of NodeIDs for the nodes to connect during a test.

Can I do this?

Currently, if I just run the https://docs.libp2p.io/guides/getting-started/go/ tutorial, after each restart, it prints a different Node ID.

```
❯ go run ./main.go
Listen addresses: /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/9436/p2p/12D3KooWNK774CCm9b48H84qZu3mp2Jq4wvDBh9813omB712qqLW
^CReceived signal, shutting down...
❯ go run ./main.go
Listen addresses: /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/9436/p2p/12D3KooWGLgDLUaNiuruX5umaExyFQJQBsf3yyXgC9MPy7cGS99F
^CReceived signal, shutting down...
```

Comment: You answered your own question? What you should have done is some searches before opening this question. And if that link is relevant but doesn't solve your problem then you should put it in your question, not post it as an answer. See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [how to ask good questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Apologies. I always first search myself. There is more than one hour between the question and my answer though. And before that, I did do quite a search. After posting my question, as I was stuck, I continued searching and bumped into that by chance...